# When $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}i]$ normal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain, euclidean-domain

Denote $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}i]=\{a+b\sqrt{n}i | a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subset \mathbb{C}$
and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}i]=\{a+b\sqrt{n} | a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

The above two rings are integral domains (as subrings of fields).

Recall that a normal domain is an integral domain which is integrally closed in its field of fractions.

In the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100639/what-are-the-integers-n-such-that-mathbbz-sqrtn-is-integrally-closed?rq=1) question, it is shown there that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{n}]$ is integrally closed in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{n})$ ($n\in\mathbb Z$, $n\neq1$) if and only if $n$ is square free and $n$ is not congruent to $1$ mod $4$ (or $n$ is a perfect square, in that case we have $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$).

> Is the above claim still valid for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}i]$ and 
>   $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}i]$?

**Edit:** After receiving an answer to one of my 'old' versions of this question, if I am not wrong, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}i]$ is a field, so the answer is that, trivially, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}i]$ is integrally closed.

It remains to deal with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}i]$ (if I am not wrong, its field of fractions is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{n}i]$).

> Does the same answer as in the above mentioned question still hold if we replace $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ by $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}i]$? (I suspect that yes).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Isn't $\sqrt{n}\,i=\sqrt {-n}$ ?

Comment: The proof doesn't assume $n>0$.  The proper overring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ (so that excludes $d=m^2$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$) is integrally closed iff $d\equiv 2,3\pmod{4}$ is square-free.

Comment: @random, I thought that in the question I have mentioned it was assumed that $n > 0$, but apparantly I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @user10354138, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Both rings are actually *fields*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess that your answer refers to one of my 'original' questions concerning $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}i]$.